# Не обновляются чанки темы Modx 1.0.5

Tags: modx

Собственно тема ModX , редактирую чанки,в админке они сохраняются. На сайте отображается инфа видимо с кэша. Очистка кэша из админки - не меняет ситуацию... Какие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

> Очистка кэша из админки - не меняет ситуацию... Какие варианты?

Попробуйте удалить кеш вручную в **assets/cache/**

> редактирую чанки,в админке они сохраняются.

Т.е. при перезагрузке страницы админки в чанках сохраняется то, что ввели ранее?!